# How to read the NDEF message? (M24SR04-Y)

Tags: c++, c, i2c, ndef

I have a microcircuit M24SR04-Y, on which I recorded information using the NFC.

I need to read this information using i2c.

I read the datasheets and understood the circuit of communication with the microcircuit.

But I am a novice and without an example it is very difficult to understand.

Tell me how and in what form to send commands. If you show an example of communication with the chip, it will be great.

Comment: You need to post some code, say what environment, platform, machine are you using, what computer language are you interested in, what kind of problem do you have. What kind of answer do you expect to get? If you understand the datasheet, then you already know. Also, here's a quick tip for you, just search in google for [M24SR04 github](https://www.google.pl/search?q=M24SR04+github) results in for example [this repo](https://github.com/gimasi/TUINO_ONE/blob/master/tuino_libs/tuino_hw/tuino_nfc/M24SR.cpp) which seems to have a driver for your device. It's easier to find examples then you think.

Comment: M24SR04 is connected to the Power PC 440EP. It is installed Linux.
I'm going to write in C / C ++.
I want to at least find out how to open I2C session in practice.

Comment: So the question is too broad. So, you are not asking on how to communicate with M24SR04 using I2C, you are asking about how to communicate with external device using I2C on Power PC 440EP with linux installed using C or C++ language? Does it has normal linux? So just using [the standard i2c linux driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface) would be the solution, if you device's kernel supports it.  Do you have any `/dev/i2c-*` device files on your platform?

Comment: I can read information from another EEPROM connected to PowerPC.
But I can not read the information from the memory of M24SR04.
Because the memory of M24SR04 cannot be accessed like a regular EEPROM.